# Use text from input field, process it within a script and then send form along with the processed text

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I can see this being a really easy request but I cannot figure it out.

I have a simple html form with consists of two fields, Name and Email.

When the form is submitted, I want to create a unique ID based on the input name and then submit the form along with the new unique ID. The form is submitted to a webhook.

so far I have the following:

HTML:

```
<form
  id="myForm"
  action="https://hook.integromat.com"
  type="POST"
>
<input type="text" name="full-name" id="name" placeholder="What's your name?" />
<input
type="email"
name="email-address"
placeholder="What's your email address?"
/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Form-submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
    function myFunction(){
        let InputName = document.getElementById('name').value
        
        
        function CreateBasename(InputName) {    
        // Change Case - START    
        const toCapitaliseCase = (phrase) => {    
            return phrase    
            .split(' ')    
            .map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))    
            .join(' ');        
        };    
        let Capitalise = toCapitaliseCase(InputName);        
        // Change Case - END    
        // return capitalise; // The ABC Company
                
        // Format Client Name if starts with 'The' - START  
        if (Capitalise.startsWith('The ')) { //The ABC Company    
            let Words = Capitalise.split(' '); //["The","ABC","Company"]    
            let The = Words[0]; // The    
            let TheSlice = Capitalise.slice(4); //ABC Company    
            let Comma = ', '; // ,    
            let BaseName = TheSlice.concat('', Comma, The); // ABC Company, The    
            return BaseName //ABC Company, The    
        }    
        // Format Client Name if it DOESN'T start with 'The' - START    
        else { //The ABC Company        
            return Capitalise    
        }  
        }
        var BaseName = CreateBasename(InputName);
        
        
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = BaseName
        return true;
        
        }
```

I just can't workout how to get the new value to be included into the form so I can send it.

Comment: Add a hidden field to the form and set the value of that field before submitting the form.  Please note:  anything you submit can be intercepted and changed by a nefarious actor.

Comment: Do you really want to expose the Integromat Webhook url?

Comment: it's my first webhook, is there a way around showing it?

Comment: I suggest you to send data (using Ajax?) to another page (PHP?), and from there to your Integromat Webhook. It's more secure.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of this. Do you have an example so I have somewhere to start?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<input type="hidden" name="unique-id">` and populate it with your js logic right before submitting the form.